# Can I convert a dynamically created c# table to a html string?

Tags: c#, html

Can I convert a dynamically created c# table to an html string ?

I mean like this;

```
Table t = new Table();
TableRow tr = new TableRow();
TableCell td = new TableCell();
td.Text = "Some text... Istanbul";
tr.Cells.Add(td);
t.Rows.Add(tr);
t.ToString();
Response.Write(t.ToString());
```

I wanna see in the page;

```
<table> <tr> <td> Some text...
 Istanbul </td> <tr> </table>
```

Comment: You should explain your question a little more...

Comment: What is a C# table?

Comment: What do you want to do? When do you need that table?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
{
  Table t = new Table();
  TableRow tr = new TableRow();
  TableCell td = new TableCell {Text = "Some text... Istanbul"};

  tr.Cells.Add(td);
  t.Rows.Add(tr);

  t.RenderControl(new HtmlTextWriter(sw));

  string html = sw.ToString();
}
```

**result:**

`<table border="0"><tr><td>Some text... Istanbul</td></tr></table>`

Answer (score 4):

You should update your question to be a little more informative. However, I will assume you are using a DataGrid:

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter(stringBuilder);  
HtmlTextWriter htmlWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter);
DataGrid1.RenderControl(htmlWriter);
string dataGridHTML = Server.HtmlEncode(stringBuilder.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

Just have a Panel on the page, and add the table to the Panel.

So, in your aspx file:

```
<asp:Panel id="MyPanel" runat="server" />
```

and in your code behind:

`MyPanel.Controls.Add(t)` // where 't' is your Table object

That places the table in your panel, which renders the Table as Html to the page, in a nice `<div>`

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It must become a string at some point for it to be rendered out to the browser - one way to do it is to take this and extract the table out of it.