# displaying values in a list onto an email row uner row

Tags: c#, list

so I am trying to display data which I got from a database onto an email.  The problem is that I put each column from a database in a list and it is putting the values all together in one row. I would like to know how it is possible if for example I have 3 values I display those 3 values under each other.  the table I did its just the loop to keep on doing it until all values of the list are put rows under each under.  below is my code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net;

namespace sql_connection
{
class Program
 {
static void Main(string[] args) 
{





    string conn = null;
    SqlConnection connection;
    conn= ("Data Source=Database\\SQL2012;Initial Catalog=jobs;User ID=user;Password=passs");

    connection = new SqlConnection(conn);
    try{

        connection.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Connection Open!");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT jobs.[dbo].[tb_work].whd_Date,jobs.[dbo].[tb_work].whd_FromTime,jobs.[dbo].[tb_work].whd_ToTime, jobs.[dbo].[tb_work].whd_User,jobs.[dbo].[tb_UserLogin].login_Email FROM jobs.[dbo].[tb_work]INNER JOIN jobs.[dbo].[tb_UserLogin] ON jobs.[dbo].[tb_work].whd_User = jobs.[dbo].[tb_UserLogin].login_LoginId WHERE  DATEDIFF(DAY,[whd_FromTime],GETDATE())<=7 AND   (whd_ToTime = '' OR whd_ToTime IS NULL) AND(whd_User=login_LoginId)");
        cmd.Connection = connection;
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        var columns = Enumerable.Range(0, reader.FieldCount).Select(reader.GetName).ToList();

        var list = new List<string>();
        var col = new List<string>();

        while(reader.Read())
        {



            var s = string.Format(" {1}     {0}         {2}       {3} ",
               reader["whd_ToTime"] == DBNull.Value? "NULL" : reader["whd_ToTime"].ToString(), 
               reader["whd_FromTime"] == DBNull.Value? "NULL" : reader["whd_FromTime"].ToString(), 

               reader["whd_User"].ToString(),
               reader["login_Email"].ToString());

              Console.WriteLine(string.Join("   ", columns.ToArray()));

            Console.WriteLine(s);
            list.Add(s);




        }

        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var s in list)
        {
            sb.AppendLine(s);
        }




        connection.Close();


        MailMessage message; 

        message=new MailMessage();
         MailAddress to = new MailAddress("xxxx@gmail.com");


        MailAddress from = new MailAddress("xxxx@gmail.com");

        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(from, to);


        mail.Subject = ("missed punch clock");

    message.IsBodyHtml = true;


            StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();

            html.AppendFormat("<!DOCTYPE html>");
            html.AppendFormat("<html><body><table>");
            html.AppendFormat("<tr><td>");

             html.Append("<table width=600px border=1 cellspacing=2 cellpadding=2 align=center bgcolor=White dir=ltr rules=all style=border-width: thin; border-style: solid; line-height: normal; vertical-align: baseline; text-align: center; font-family: Calibri; font-size: medium; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; color: #000000; list-style-type: none;>");
             for (int rowind = 0; rowind < 1; rowind++)
             {
                 html.Append("<tr>");
                 html.Append("<td>");
                 html.Append("<table width=600px border=1 cellspacing=2 cellpadding=2 align=center bgcolor=White dir=ltr rules=all style=border-width: thin; border-style: solid; line-height: normal; vertical-align: baseline; text-align: center; font-family: Calibri; font-size: medium; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; color: #000000; list-style-type: none;>");

                 for (int newrowind = 0; newrowind < 1; newrowind++)
                 {


                     html.AppendFormat("<tr>");
                     html.Append("<td colspan=1  style=font-weight:bold>");
                     html.Append("whd_FromTime");
                     html.Append("</td>");
                     html.Append("<td colspan=2 style=font-weight:bold>");
                     html.Append("whd_ToTime");
                     html.Append("</td>");
                     html.Append("<td colspan=3 style=font-weight:bold>");
                     html.Append("whd_User");
                     html.Append("</td>");
                     html.Append("</tr>");

                         html.AppendFormat("<tr>");

                         html.Append("<td colspan=1  style=font-weight:bold>");
                         for(int i=0;i <col.Count;i++) 
                         {
                             html.Append("</br>");
                             html.Append(pb.ToString());
                             html.Append("</br>");

                         }

                           html.Append("</td>");


                         html.Append("<td colspan=2  style=font-weight:bold>");
                         html.Append(sb.ToString());

                         html.Append("</td>");
                         html.Append("<td colspan=3  style=font-weight:bold>");
                         html.Append(cb.ToString());


                         html.Append("</td>");    
                     html.Append("</tr>");



                 }

                 html.Append("</tr>");
                 html.Append("</td>");
                 html.Append("</table>");
             }
             html.Append("</table>");
             html.AppendFormat("</td></tr>");
             html.AppendFormat("</table></html></body>");


                mail.Body= html.ToString();
                mail.IsBodyHtml = true;          SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        smtp.Port = 587;

        smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(
            "xxxx"gmail.com", xxxxxxxx");
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        Console.WriteLine("Sending email..");
        smtp.Send(mail);
    } 




    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }





}
}
 }
```

Comment: Why are you repeating yourself? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30525199/structuring-a-table-in-an-email/30526212#30526212

Comment: because im trying to finish this, searched the whole interne to make a loop to show each value in a list under each under but nobody answered back so I did a new one with the new code maybe someone could help me doo this.

Comment: Doesn't mean you should ask it twice - you can edit your first question.

Comment: okay good to know. Now by any chance do you know how for every value in a list you make a new row and put a value?

Comment: <tr><td>value</td></tr>?