# How to build a html table dynamically based on dataset

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a dataset

```
DataSet ds = Access.Get(startdate, enddate);
```

I returns me about 70 rows.I need to build an html table based on this to provide printing option. Any suggestions on how to do this? Thanks

Comment: The first 2 options I think about are nested loops or Linq. What have you tried?

Comment: I have done this with datatables but am stuck with dataset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass DataSet table to ConvertDataSetTableToHTML. Ensure your dataset always have table with records before calling.

```
if (ds != null)
{
    if (ds.Tables.Count >0 )
    {
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            ConvertDataSetTableToHTML(ds.Tables[0]);
        }
    }
}
public static string ConvertDataSetTableToHTML(DataTable dt)
{
    string html = "<table>";
    //add header row
    html += "<tr>";
    for(int i=0;i<dt.Columns.Count;i++)
        html+="<td>"+dt.Columns[i].ColumnName+"</td>";
    html += "</tr>";
    //add rows
    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        html += "<tr>";
        for (int j = 0; j< dt.Columns.Count; j++)
            html += "<td>" + dt.Rows[i][j].ToString() + "</td>";
        html += "</tr>";
    }
    html += "</table>";
    return html;
}
```

I just used the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19682996/datatable-to-html-table) for your scenario.

Comment: But how to add the returned html to the aspx page

Comment: Can you try creating `div` in aspx like `<div id="divDynamicHTMLTable" runat="server"></div>` and in code behind file, `divDynamicHTMLTable.InnerHtml= ConvertDataSetTableToHTML(ds.Tables[0]);`? Place code behind change inside if condition by replacing `ConvertDataSetTableToHTML(ds.Tables[0]);`. I don't have VS with me at the moment, so try and let me know

Comment: I tried this and it worked    <asp:Label ID="lblResult" runat="server"/> and  string result = ConvertDataSetTableToHTML(dsPNPrint.Tables[0]);
                       lblResult.Text = result;

Comment: Glad to hear. Can you mark the solution as answered?

Comment: But the styles are not applying. Any idea why?

Comment: Styles? Can you create a new post with screenshot? This would help to understand. Also, post the code created for style